# Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions in dispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to create a signout and login functionality for my application.

I added redux to do this, but I am getting the error mentioned in the title.

Here is my code:

> App.js

This is my main component and here is my Router for the app

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./Redux/store";

import { Login } from "./Components/Login";
import Signup from "./Components/Signup";
import { MainTheme } from "./Components/MainTheme";

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
          <Route path="/signup" exact component={Signup} />
          <Route path="/" exact component={MainTheme} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

> Signup.js

Is the component for Signup and is where the error appears. Specifically in my function called in mapDispatchToProps

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { userPostFetch } from "../../Redux/actions";

const Signup = ({ userPostFetch }) => {
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const signupFrm = e.target;

    const user = {
      username: signupFrm.username.value,
      email: signupFrm.email.value,
      password: signupFrm.password.value,
      confPassword: signupFrm.confPassword.value,
    };

    userPostFetch(user);
  };

  return (
    <div className="min-h-screen flex items-center justify-center bg-gray-50 py-12 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
      <div className="max-w-md w-full space-y-8">
        <div>
          <h2 className="mt-6 text-center text-3xl font-extrabold text-gray-900">
            Sign up
          </h2>
        </div>
        <form className="mt-8 space-y-6" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input type="hidden" name="remember" value="true" />
          <div className="rounded-md shadow-sm -space-y-px">
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="username" className="sr-only">
                Username
              </label>
              <input
                id="username"
                name="username"
                type="text"
                required
                className="appearance-none rounded-none relative block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-500 text-gray-900 rounded-t-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:z-10 sm:text-sm"
                placeholder="Username"
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="email-address" className="sr-only">
                Email address
              </label>
              <input
                id="email-address"
                name="email"
                type="email"
                autoComplete="email"
                required
                className="appearance-none rounded-none relative block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-500 text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:z-10 sm:text-sm"
                placeholder="Email address"
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="password" className="sr-only">
                Password
              </label>
              <input
                id="password"
                name="password"
                type="password"
                autoComplete="current-password"
                required
                className="appearance-none rounded-none relative block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-500 text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:z-10 sm:text-sm"
                placeholder="Password"
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="confirm-password" className="sr-only">
                Confirm Password
              </label>
              <input
                id="confirm-password"
                name="confPassword"
                type="password"
                required
                className="appearance-none rounded-none relative block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-500 text-gray-900 rounded-b-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:z-10 sm:text-sm"
                placeholder="Confirm  Password"
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div>
            <button className="group relative w-full flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">
              <span className="absolute left-0 inset-y-0 flex items-center pl-3">
                {/* Heroicon name: lock-closed */}
                <svg
                  className="h-5 w-5 text-indigo-500 group-hover:text-indigo-400"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                  fill="currentColor"
                  aria-hidden="true"
                >
                  <path
                    fillRule="evenodd"
                    d="M5 9V7a5 5 0 0110 0v2a2 2 0 012 2v5a2 2 0 01-2 2H5a2 2 0 01-2-2v-5a2 2 0 012-2zm8-2v2H7V7a3 3 0 016 0z"
                    clipRule="evenodd"
                  />
                </svg>
              </span>
              Sign in
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

**The error is in this function**
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  userPostFetch: (userInfo) => {
    dispatch(userPostFetch(userInfo));
  },
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Signup);
```

> Actions.js

The action for the functionality

```
export const userPostFetch = (user) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return fetch("http://0.0.0.0:3001/signup", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ user }),
    })
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((data) => {
        if (data.error) {
          // Here you should have logic to handle invalid creation of a user.
          // This assumes your Rails API will return a JSON object with a key of
          // 'message' if there is an error with creating the user, i.e. invalid username
          (data.error.code === 11000) ? console.log(`Code: ${data.error.code} = ${data.error.KeyPatter} duplicado`) : console.log(`Code: ${data.error.code}`);
        } else {
          localStorage.setItem("token", data.token);
          dispatch(loginUser(data.user));
        }
      });
  };
};

const loginUser = (userObj) => ({
  type: "LOGIN_USER",
  payload: userObj,
});
```

> store.js

The intial state of the store and the reducer

```
import { createStore } from "redux";

const initialState = {
  currentUser: {},
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOGIN_USER":
      return { ...state, currentUser: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default createStore(reducer);
```

> The error gets after click the submit button. I think that i need use a middleware but I really don't know how or what must I do?

Comment: As the error says, you need middleware (like `redux-thunk`) to do async stuff in actions

Comment: Thanks!! I've used this [redux-thunk docs](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) for the solution

Answer (score 0):

Just used redux-thunk for solution:

**sudo npm i redux-thunk**

> store.js (modified)

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk"

const initialState = {
  currentUser: {},
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOGIN_USER":
      return { ...state, currentUser: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```